# WinError 10054, An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: python, google-translate, translate, xlrd

It shows the error like this

> httpcore._exceptions.ConnectError: [WinError 10054] An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

result = translator.translate('重', src='ja', dest='en')
print(result.text)
```

Comment: Looks like the module is broken or you have hit a rate limit. Did you send many translation requests or did this always fail?

Comment: Module is broken, they're not passing Travis builds. When I tried this code I got AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. The connection being closed by remote host seems like a rate limit, or something else is wrong with the module.

Comment: No, I did not send many translation requests, It was failing always.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of googletrans is having issues.
Please uninstall it and then again install it using the command

```
pip install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

Answer (score 0):

i've been face the same issue, in my case it cause the large of dataset that can't support by my device,  i solved it by preprocessing(clean,stopword) my dataset first and try to translate again but if it won't work  maybe you can split dataset into some part of data then translate and then merge again. or you can limit your length of word in every raw by code

```
max_size = 5000 
dataset['res'] = dataset['Tweets'].str.split(n=max_size).str[:max_size].str.join(' ')
```